# Scrapy crawl on crontab under virtual environment

Tags: virtualenv, cron, scrapy

Trying to run scrapy crawl command using crontab under virtual environment, and getting below error while running scrapy command from cron job -

```
     UserWarning: Cannot import scrapy settings module myspider.settings warnings.warn("Cannot import scrapy settings module
 %s" % scrapy_module) 
     ..... 
     raise KeyError("Spider not found: %s" % spider_name) KeyError: 'Spider not found: myspider'
```

Any help or suggestion?

Comment: what's the user account you are running it under in cron?

Comment: How does the cron command look like?

Comment: @DrColossos -  */40 * * * * source /home/water/.virtualenvs/water/bin/activate && cd $HOME/water2012/ && scrapy crawl water2012 >> $HOME/water2012/log/log_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d).log 2>&1

Comment: @Leo - Its running under account id on server - water

Comment: can you run the scrapy crawl command from a shell session under the same account without problems?

Comment: yes, it runs fine under shell. The same command. I think its because of some environment variable its not getting while running under cron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was missing PYTHONPATH while running under crontab.

I have added it before my following cron job:

> */40 * * * * source /home/water/.virtualenvs/water/bin/activate && cd
>   $HOME/water2012/ && scrapy crawl water2012 >>
>   $HOME/water2012/log/log_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d).log 2>&1